# How to use intent.extra in fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a question about fragment activity and activity in the android studio. I want to use intent to send the data to other fragments but the code found is only used for activity.

- First fragment to tranfer data

```html
holder.recCard.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, DetailFragment::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Image", dataList[holder.adapterPosition].dataImage)
            intent.putExtra("Description", dataList[holder.adapterPosition].dataDesc)
            intent.putExtra("Title", dataList[holder.adapterPosition].dataTitle)
            intent.putExtra("Priority", dataList[holder.adapterPosition].dataPriority)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

- The fragment to received data

```html
 val bundle = intent.extras
        if (bundle != null) {
            binding.detailDesc.text = bundle.getString("Description")
            binding.detailTitle.text = bundle.getString("Title")
            binding.detailPriority.text = bundle.getString("Priority")
            imageURL = bundle.getString("Image")!!
            Glide.with(this).load(bundle.getString("Image"))
                .into(binding.detailImage)
        }
```

But for the `val bundle = intent.extras`, it got an error that cannot use intent directly. How I can solve it?

Comment: `intent` is a property on `Activity` not `Fragment`. Try the fragment's `activity` property. Also review: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate